# Attention Something went wrong. Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state

Tags: error, error-message

Magento 2.4.1

I did a new install of Magento 2.4.1 without sample data. I haven't really done anything with it except to set up 4 websites/stores/store fronts/domains.

Now, out of nowhere, anything I click on brings up the following pop-up Error:

**Attention
Something went wrong.**

There is also this message on the page itself:

**Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.**

I also got this Error:

**A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.**

*Now when I go to Catalog --) Products, the Error messages pop up twice. I click OK on it but the actual page never loads!* ***It is stuck with the loading circle going round and round and round...***

I tried the following:

- deleted Cache
- reindexed
- upgraded PHP to 7.4 and restarted the whole server

var\log\debug.log:

```
[2021-01-13 08:47:03] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:03] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.17791295051575,"count":1,"realmem":6291456,"emalloc":7401400,"realmem_start":55050240,"emalloc_start":52032800} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:03] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:03] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0064380168914795,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1512,"realmem_start":61341696,"emalloc_start":59467096} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00033402442932129,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":61341696,"emalloc_start":59645592} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0003199577331543,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":61341696,"emalloc_start":59650656} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00034093856811523,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":61341696,"emalloc_start":59655080} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.062521934509277,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":134768,"realmem_start":55050240,"emalloc_start":51813296} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.037412166595459,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":540336,"realmem_start":55050240,"emalloc_start":51351512} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00031590461730957,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":61341696,"emalloc_start":59659504} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.01816987991333,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":256304,"realmem_start":55050240,"emalloc_start":51896312} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00031089782714844,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1024,"realmem_start":63438848,"emalloc_start":62459208} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00035190582275391,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":65536000,"emalloc_start":62978504} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00036501884460449,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":65536000,"emalloc_start":63454936} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job yotpo_yotpo_orders_sync is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00038909912109375,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":65536000,"emalloc_start":63915888} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0010669231414795,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1504,"realmem_start":65536000,"emalloc_start":63941264} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00026988983154297,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":65536000,"emalloc_start":64028800} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0010178089141846,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":5744,"realmem_start":65536000,"emalloc_start":64039136} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_attribute_value_synchronize is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_attribute_value_synchronize is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0019850730895996,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":24824,"realmem_start":65536000,"emalloc_start":64158240} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00029706954956055,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1008,"realmem_start":67633152,"emalloc_start":65449752} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job newsletter_send_all is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job yotpo_yotpo_orders_sync is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.3368091583252,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1425792,"realmem_start":55050240,"emalloc_start":51725800} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job newsletter_send_all is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.011765003204346,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":613920,"realmem_start":67633152,"emalloc_start":65459472} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job get_amazon_capture_updates is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job get_amazon_capture_updates is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.010025024414062,"count":1,"realmem":2621440,"emalloc":2787440,"realmem_start":67633152,"emalloc_start":66806216} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job get_amazon_authorization_updates is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job get_amazon_authorization_updates is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0056538581848145,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":238448,"realmem_start":72351744,"emalloc_start":70116192} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job amazon_payments_process_queued_refunds is run [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:05] main.INFO: Cron Job amazon_payments_process_queued_refunds is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.005565881729126,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":302464,"realmem_start":72351744,"emalloc_start":70369776} [] []
```

var\log\system.log:

```
#0 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(655): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('setup:cron')
#1 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(235): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('setup:cron:run')
#2 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(147): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/mywebsite/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#5 {main} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:20:08] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:23:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:26:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:29:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:31:02] main.ERROR: There are no commands defined in the "setup:cron" namespace.

Did you mean one of these?
    setup
    setup:config
    setup:db
    setup:db-data
    setup:db-declaration
    setup:db-schema
    setup:di
    setup:performance
    setup:static-content
    setup:store-config
#0 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(655): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('setup:cron')
#1 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(235): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('setup:cron:run')
#2 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(147): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/mywebsite/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#5 {main} [] []
[2021-01-13 08:32:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:35:08] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:38:04] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:41:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:44:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-01-13 08:47:04] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
```

Why is this all of a sudden popping up after anything I click on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check is elasticsearch work well

Comment: @Siarhey Uchukhlebau Thank you for the suggestion, however, I asked my hosting company to check this and they replied with: I have reviewed the Elasticsearch service and I confirm that the same is currently fully operational. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to solve it by cleaning the database table with `TRUNCATE ui_bookmark;` if it doesn't solve the issue, you can try to increase the session limit.

[image: Magento 2 admin user session]